# Lack of jQuery Mobile js disorder some elements on my page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i'm making a webpage and I decided to take out the jQuery mobile JS file because it was to heavy for my page and it wasn't necesary anymore, but when I take it off some elements get disordered with no reason. Please if someone can explain why does this happen, tell me. I can reorder them rapidly but I want to know why this happens.

This is how it looks with JQUERY MOBILE:

[image]

This is how it looks without it:

[image]

Here's the web: http://www.sinvenderse.com/reiki/index.htm

Comment: This is a CSS issue. When your remove jQM, its' CSS classes aren't applied anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Render it with jQM then copy result of form with Chrome Developer Tool to the html that do not include jQM should solve your problem.

i.e.:Replace with the following html.

```
<form data-ajax="false" method="post" action="send.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="recipient" value="info@hgstudio.com.ar">
            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Pruebas Reiki">
            <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="gracias.htm">

            <p class="formu" style="top: 5px; left: 63px">Suscribite a nuestras novedades</p>
                <br>
                <span class="formu sml" style="bottom: 5px; right: 9px">NOMBRES</span>
                <input type="text" name="name" id="nomb" class="formu" style="bottom: 6px; right: 5px; -webkit-box-shadow: rgb(191, 96, 96) 0px 0px 3px 2px;">
                <br>
                <span class="formu sml" style="left: 24px">MAIL</span>
                <input type="email" name="email" id="corr" class="formu" style="bottom: 1px; left: 29px">
                <br>
                <img src="image-captcha.php" draggable="false" class="formu" alt="captcha-recarga-la-pagina" style="left: 42px; top: 6px">
                <input type="text" name="captcha" id="ver" style="width: 100px; left: 36px" class="formu">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" id="oc" class="formu" value="Enviar" style="width: 70px; top: 0px; left: 40px">
            </form>
```

If it still not work, try to include jQM css too.

This is because jQM will select all matched elements contain certain data-* and class then change HTML structure and add styling classes to all further.

If it is still not working, you can check to see if you used any jQM classes that will trigger jQM further modifying classes and html

Comment: Thanks! I deleted the JQM and rearrenged the elements manually but I could understand why that happened!